# Return a triangled-shaped list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

How can I return a triangle-shaped list of lists from a specified number?

Example:

```
>>> myList = triangle(3)
             [0,0,0]
             [1,1]
             [2]
>>> myList 
[[0,0,0], [1,1], [2]]
```

Comment: What is "a given number into a triangle array?"  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. What im trying to say is whatever number you input into triangle function ex: triangle(8) it displays that number in a downward triangle. I was thinking of using a list function along with an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def triangle(n):
    a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        b=[]
        for j in range(n-i):
            b.append(i)
        a.append(b)
    for row in a:
        print row
```

Edit: Changed the code so that the function prints the element in triangle shape.

Comment: This is what I had, the only part I had trouble with is making it into a triangle.

Comment: @ChrisDavies , it is not clear to me what do you mean by a triangle? Are you interested in printing these elements in triangle shape?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @ChrisDevies , edited the code so that it prints the elements in triangle shape now.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
def triangle(number):
    return [[n]*(number-n) for n in range(number)]
```

Sample outputs:

```
>>> triangle(4)
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3]]
>>> triangle(5)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4]]
>>> triangle(3)
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2]]
```

Printing a triangle:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str, triangle(3)))
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2]
```